# What is the correct word for a type shorthand in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, computer-science, keyword

For example:

```
100M is decimal
100l is long
```

I wanted to find one for a unit, so I don't have to type `(uint) 123` all the time and I realised I didn't know what word to search for.

Comment: `u` ................................

Comment: You are looking for **U**!!!

Comment: Se [_integer-type-suffix_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx) in the specification (the _real-type-suffix_ is in the next section, but you didn't ask for them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just talking about terminology, *literal* is a value specified directly in source, such as:

10
   10M
   100L
   "this is a regular string literal"
   @"this is a verbatim string literal"
   '\u000'
   '\n'
   'X'

A numeric literal can include a *suffix* (`l`/`L`, `u`/`U`, `ul`/`UL`, `m`/`M`, `f`/`F`, `d`/`D`) to give more information about the type of value being represented.

In terms of the literal suffix for `uint`, it's `U` or `u`. This works for both `uint` and `ulong` in fact; a literal value smaller than or equal to `unit.MaxValue` will be implicitly `uint`; a larger value will be implicitly `ulong`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) or the C# language spec section 2.4.4 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For UInt you can use 'U' char:

`uint i = 123U;`

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Had a brain wave.  It's a **literal**

`100l, 100m, 100u` etc are all literals.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is Literal. For example the Literal suffix for uint(as everyone has said) is U. so you would have 123U.